# Configure Basic Auth in Apache 2.4 which is running as a load balancer

Tags: apache, load-balancing, basic-authentication

I have Apache 2.4 running as a load balancer in front of Tomcat App servers. It's all running on Linux in AWS. Since this is a test environment accessible from the Internet, I would like, as an additional security layer, protect it with Basic Auth configured in that Apache 2.4 web server which is running as a load balancer. I did quite a bit of googling for a solution, but so far was unable to find any config options which work in my case. Any help is highly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Might help to have an idea of what didn't work.

Comment: This config was tried and didn't work: `<         AuthType basic
<         AuthName “TTA_auth_name”
<         AuthUserFile “/etc/httpd/passwd/passwords”
<         Require valid-user`

Comment: That was added to ssl.conf

Comment: Basic question just to make sure, is mod_auth_basic loaded ? Also, those directives go normally within a Directory or Location container, were they ?

Comment: When I run 'apachectl -t -D DUMP_MODULES' it lists ' auth_basic_module (shared)' among other things. So, I assume that the basic auth module is installed. What should I check to answer your questions about the directives?

Comment: Well normally, AuthType, AuthUserFile, etc... go within a Directory or Location container, as they refer to access to specific portion of the site (could be / though for everything). I was asking that it was where they were.

Comment: The said config was applied to a Location in ssl.conf...

Comment: Then I'm out of option without looking at the whole configuration. Worth to mention that I don't use/know AWS. Did you ask their support ? They might have specific procedure/configuration to acheive that.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The basic auth config was applied to a wrong Location tag in our ssl.conf. Thanks to Andre Gelinas for bringing Locations to my attention!